# Injecting Multiple Dependencies in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a angular app which I have used ng-route dependency. My app works fine with following code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Now am trying to implement angular.chosen in the app, which I have to inject angular.chosen in my module to work. I am unaware of injecting multiple dependencies in the module. I tried with the following code, but that did not work out.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','angular.chosen']);
```

Please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: it is correct , but what is angular.chosen?

Comment: http://adityasharat.github.io/angular-chosen/

Comment: Angular-Chosen is an angular directive that can be used to convert select boxes to a more user-friendly chosen drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the necessary references in the index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://github.com/adityasharat/angular-chosen/blob/master/angular-chosen.js">
<script src="../modules/app.module.js"></script>
```